# Remove clumps of pixels in R

Tags: raster, r, remote-sensing, clustering, erdas-imagine

I would like to **remove isolated pixels** (or clumps of pixels <9) from my raster image.

```
library(raster)
# create some raster data
r <- raster(ncols=12, nrows=12)
set.seed(0)
r[] <- round(runif(ncell(r))*0.7 )
rc <- clump(r)
```

**Before removing clumps of pixels <9**

[image]

**After removing clumps of pixels <9** :

[image]

In Erdas, there is the **Sieve tool** to do this, but how to replace it in R?

Comment: Look at "Applying a raster sieve by clumping" in [Lesson 7: Advanced Raster Analysis](https://geoscripting-wur.github.io/AdvancedRasterAnalysis/)

Comment: Great, thank you very much, I din´t know this site! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#reproducible example
r <- raster(ncols=12, nrows=12)
set.seed(0)
r[] <- round(runif(ncell(r))*0.7 )
rc <- clump(r) 

#extract IDs of clumps according to some criteria
clump9 = data.frame(freq(rc))
clump9 = clump9[ ! clump9$count < 9, ] #remove clump observations with frequency smaller than 9
clump9 = as.vector(clump9$value) # record IDs from clumps which met the criteria in previous step

rc[rc != clump9[1] & rc != clump9[2]] = NA #replace cells with IDs which do not belong to the group of interest 

plot(rc,col="black",legend=FALSE)
```

[image]

Note that from the `clump` function, the clump ID "4" had 2 cells in the right side connecting with cells on the left.

```
head(rc)
    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
1  NA NA NA NA  2 NA  2  2 NA NA NA NA
2  NA NA NA  2 NA  2  2 NA  2  2 NA NA
3  NA NA NA NA NA  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA
4  NA  4 NA  2 NA  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA
5  NA  4 NA NA  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
6  NA  4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
7   4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
8  NA  4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  4  4
9   4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
10 NA  4 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: Thanks Andre, I´ve already realized it and I have used extend tool     r2<-extend(r, c(1,1))

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to @gene and https://geoscripting-wur.github.io/AdvancedRasterAnalysis/ I can now answer my question (copied and modified):

library(raster)

```
# create some raster data
r <- raster(ncols=12, nrows=12)
set.seed(0)
r[] <- round(runif(ncell(r))*0.7 )
r[r==0]<-NA

# extend r with a number of rows and culomns (at each side)
# to isolate clumps adjacents to plot axes 
r2<-extend(r, c(1,1))
rc <- clump(r2, directions = 8) 

# get frequency table    
f<-freq(rc)
# save frequency table as data frame
f<-as.data.frame(f)

# which rows of the data.frame are only represented by clumps under 9pixels?
str(which(f$count <= 9))
# which values do these correspond to?
str(f$value[which(f$count <= 9)])
# put these into a vector of clump ID's to be removed
excludeID <- f$value[which(f$count <= 9)]

# make a new raster to be sieved
formaskSieve <- rc
# assign NA to all clumps whose IDs are found in excludeID
formaskSieve[rc %in% excludeID] <- NA

plot(formaskSieve)
```

and **result wanted** (with one row and one column of NA added on each side of raster).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An additional answer for projected data. `bfastSpatial::areaSieve()` takes a threshold argument, such that clumps smaller than the threshold are removed.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bfastSpatial/versions/0.6.2/topics/areaSieve